# Mysql Helm chart keeps on restarting

Tags: mysql, azure-aks, bitnami

I'm running following [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mysql) for my Mysql db running in azure aks. Initially the db was running as intended, until this log started appearing:

`[Warning] [MY-013360] [Server] Plugin mysql_native_password reported: ''mysql_native_password' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use caching_sha2_password instead'`

The suggestions [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/18606) were applied to fix the issue but the log statement still appears

After upgrading the chart the pods continue to shutdown with the following log:
`[System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.35).`

These are my custom values added to the version 9.14.1

```
architecture: replication
secondary:
  replicaCount: 2

metrics:
  enabled: true
```

I'm able to port-forward the mysql-metrics service, but not sure what to look for in the logs.

This is a small database consisting of 5 tables and less than 1000 rows in each

Looking at the event for the namespace there isn't enough memory:
`The node was low on resource: memory. Container mysql was using 421440Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container metrics was using 15092Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.`

But after enabling autoscaling the pods still restart

Answer (score 0):

The warning is just informational and shouldn't result in pod restarts. The issue you're facing is likely related to some other configuration issue.  As per the [Excessive logging thread](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/18606) , instead of helm upgrading, try creating a fresh namespace and helm install it fresh after adding the [test.yaml](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/18606#:%7E:text=$%20cat%20test.yaml%0Aprimary:%0A%20%20configuration:%20%7C-%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bmysqld%5D%0A%20%20%20%20default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password%0A%20%20%20%20skip,sock%0A%20%20%20%20pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid)

it should work fine as you can see in the log-

```
2023-10-27T09:44:21.538670Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-10-27T09:44:21.704571Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-10-27T09:44:21.911205Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-10-27T09:44:21.911239Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-10-27T09:44:21.926974Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /tmp/mysqlx.sock
2023-10-27T09:44:21.927008Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution.
```

[image]

I am using the mysql helm-chart as below-

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl create namespace mysql
namespace/mysql created
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl get ns
NAME                STATUS   AGE
default             Active   16m
gatekeeper-system   Active   16m
kube-node-lease     Active   16m
kube-public         Active   16m
kube-system         Active   16m
mysql               Active   3s
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=mysql
Context "MySQL" modified.
PS C:\Windows\system32> helm install mysql azure-marketplace/mysql
NAME: mysql
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Oct 27 15:12:59 2023
NAMESPACE: mysql
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
CHART NAME: mysql
CHART VERSION: 9.4.3
APP VERSION: 8.0.31

** Please be patient while the chart is being deployed **

Tip:

  Watch the deployment status using the command: kubectl get pods -w --namespace mysql

Services:

  echo Primary: mysql.mysql.svc.cluster.local:3306

Execute the following to get the administrator credentials:

  echo Username: root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace mysql mysql -o jsonpath="{.data.mysql-root-password}" | base64 -d)
```

[image]

Pods are up

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> kubectl get pods
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-0        1/1     Running   0          11m
mysql-client   1/1     Running   0          4m41s
```

[image]

Can access the database
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)